# AWS EB - How to map a subdomain to CNAME, and www to another CNAME?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I've never done any kind of domain setup before, so I'm just following the AWS documentation.

I've purchased a domain on Google Domains.  I've got my REST API application deployed on AWS ElasticBeanstalk.  I've also got my front end application deployed there, but for now I just want to deploy my REST API.

Is this possible?

`www.mydomain.com` CNAME `my-frontend-app.some-az.elasticbeanstalk.com`

`api.mydomain.com` CNAME `my-rest-api-app.some-az.elasticbeanstalk.com`

`*.mydomain.com` -> redirect -> `https://*.mydomain.com`?

Are these things something I have to do in the Google Domains console?  Here's what the console looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first two options should be possible using [Google Domains console](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart)
`www.mydomain.com CNAME my-frontend-app.some-az.elasticbeanstalk.com`
`api.mydomain.com CNAME my-rest-api-app.some-az.elasticbeanstalk.com`

`*.mydomain.com -> redirect -> https://*.mydomain.com` is not only a DNS configuration, it involves using SSL certificates and redirect from port 80 to 443. For this step, you can create a AWS CloudFront Distribution and map the distribution CName to *.mydomain.com in Google Domains console. Since AWS provides free SSL certificates, you can configure and attach it to CloudFront and do the redirection from there.

Comment: This works, but needs more info.  In CloudFront, you also need to configure the Alternate Domain Name to `*.example.com` and you need something behind CloudFront to actually issue the redirect.  Could be your app server or could be an empty S3 bucket with web site hosting and "redirect all requests..." set to the desired target hostname for the redirects.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to do this without cloudfront?  I am using nginx for proxy server, and I'm trying to read the documentation on using ebextensions to add a redirect.  However, I'm afraid I will nuke the existing configuration since I'm not very familiar with nginx.  if I ssh into instance I can see the nginx configuration at /etc/nginx/ so I'm wondering if I just append it in here.

Comment: You can do it without CloudFront. What you need to make sure is, Elastic Beanstalk should be able to create new instance based on your configuration automatically. So either you need to create a script to automate this and add that to the launch configuration or create a new AMI after modifying the configuration to be used by Elastic Beanstalk.